# Wordpress development, team collaboration and Mysql

Tags: mysql, database

How to collaborate with other developers for the development of a Wordpress website? For files, we use GIT but how share/version the database?

Currently we use an online database that we copy locally to be up to date. And when we need to change the wordpress' configuration or adding a post, we do that on the online DataBase and we pull the new version locally.

What is your process to do that? A plugin that log all SQL queries and can be reload locally and test conflicts?